# How to get another column in a dataframe filled with values from another columns based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe with 6 columns:

```
Id  count1  Value1  count2  Value2  Value3  
1    1200      3     2000       4       6     
2    100       2     400        5       8     
3    800       4     1100       7       9
```

I need to get a new column with following conditions:
if count 1 > 1000, new column should take values from Value1 column.
elif count 2 > 1000, new column should take values from Value2 column.
else, new column should be filled with values from Value 3.

Output should look like:

```
Id  count1  Value1  count2  Value2  Value3  New Column
1    1200      3     2000       4       6     3
2    100       2     400        5       8     8
3    800       4     1100       7       9     7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [np.select()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
import numpy  as np

condlist=[(df['count1'] > 1000),(df['count2'] > 1000) & (df['count1'] <= 1000)]
choicelist=[df['Value1'], df['Value2']]
default=df['Value3']

df['new_column']=np.select(condlist,choicelist,default)
```